# ARSCNView Corner Radius not showing

Tags: swift, arkit, arscnview, sceneview

I have a corner radius on my `ARSCNView` as below;

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        sceneView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        sceneView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        sceneView.clipsToBounds = true
    }
```

However, it is only showing when you enter app in background as illustrated below;

[image: image of app in background]

As soon as the app is in the foreground the corner radius goes back to 0.

Ive tried adding in `ViewDidLoad` & `ViewWillAppear` no success

Comment: If i remember correctly you have to restart the `scene` and setup all the settings for it again.

Comment: can you please elaborate with an example? thanks

Comment: Store `let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()` in the view or viewcontroller that you use.. and then in viewWillAppear you call upon your scenView (the ARSCNView) like this `sceneView.session.run(configuration)` followed by `layoutSubviews()` so you will update your layer. Can't promise this is the solution tho. was quite a while ago i worked with AR

Answer (score 0):

I just tried with just

```
sceneView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
```

without `masksToBounds` and `clipsToBounds` and it worked for me.

If you're `sceneView` is inside another view or the root view of your view controller, check the background of that view and make sure it's something noticeable.

Maybe the `sceneView` itself is larger than the phones screen. Check the frame size or the layout constraints and make sure they are not causing the `sceneView` to stretch outside the phone screen edges.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: If this doesn't work. There's a similar question may be a duplicate of this one. So you can continue the discussion there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54922139/how-to-clip-arscnview-bounds-to-circle